# Most simple "Word hunter" example for GAE MapReduce Library

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

Up until now I cannot find a really concise working example for the GAE MapReduce library.

Much are plain snippets if not ideas. The example that Google provides is quite not easy to understand consisting of pipelined Jobs etc.

I have a data in the datastore that which I need to check each one using MapReduce to check if a given word exist, and if it does, update the `boolean wordFound` to `true` field on the same Datastore entity.

How can I easily do this with GAE MapReduce library?